# Problem in understanding bridge rectifier

Tags: diodes, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

Why does electricity not flow from the other two diodes after it has been through the load in a full wave bridge rectifier?
I'd asked this question on Physics SE but was told to ask it here.[image]

Comment: Because the P-N junctions are reverse-biased.

Comment: Because that (what Ignacio said) is what diodes do. I'd recommend reading the Wikipedia article on diodes, which you *should* have found when researching bridge rectifier via Google (via Wikipedia's "diode bridge" page)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic due to lacking basic research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with the comments made about lack of basic research before asking the question.This topic is well covered on the net, in books etc.

Consider a voltage across a diode. For a diode to conduct **the anode voltage must be more positive than the cathode**.

When a diode conducts there is **a forward drop in voltage**. This voltage will vary with the current through the diode (often more than 1V) but lets assume a minimum value of 0.7V for a silicon diode.

**Voltages are always relative** so in a transformer /bridge rectifier circuit we can take our '0V' (ground) from the perspective of the transformer or the load. Normally we take the load. Either way it makes absolutely no difference to the voltage **across** the diodes and the direction of current.

You **always get two diodes that can't conduct** because they are reverse biased and **two diodes that do conduct giving a 2xVd voltage drop** from the transformer to the load.

The voltage across and current through the load is always in the same direction.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't find an answer anywhere else... BTW thanx for your help

Comment: Because it loses energy and therefore voltage  (energy = eV)  - think of it as a staircase  - you roll a ball from the top of the stairs and it falls to the bottom - it doesn't magically jump back up to the top. For a diode to conduct it must be forward biased i.e. the anode must be more positive than the cathode.

Comment: Nice answer, but to be pedantic. The diodes DO all conduct at once. However the reverse biased diodes have a very large resistance while the forward biased diodes have a very low resistance. So almost the entirety of the current flows though the forward biased path.

Comment: @Trevor Yes, I totally agree, that would be pedantic, correct but pedantic.